# "Пусть расползётся пэрча" - what does it mean?

Tags: значения, выражения

Can anyone help me understand what this phrase means? “пусть расползётся пэрча”

I’m sure it’s grammatically incorrect but I couldn’t find a proper interpretation of it.

I’m not understanding пэрча. I tried google translate it but it gives me a weird word. It says “let the parcha creep”. Unfortunately, a friend had posted on VK but for personal reasons I can’t ask him.

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly is causing trouble understanding it? Is it one of the words (like _пэрча_ which I haven't seen before) or the grammatical structure of the phrase? The context you saw or heard this phrase in would also help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi I edited the question. If anything else is needed for clarification let me know

Comment: for me, it looks like a replacement(not a specific one) of a swear word, just a bit more creative one, it can be incorrect, but it would be the way I would read it. And you definitely can ask using swear words as well - what the heck is that stuff (if you on equal footing, not superior by age or else). in some sense, the thing is funny because the word can mean anything and it is fun to replace it with different words and as a potential way to hit a conversation and create a discussion.

Comment: If it's actually "порча" (rather than "туча" from OCR), then the phrase sounds like a witch's spell (let the jinx spread out).

Comment: The way it was written it was something like: пусть расползётся пэээрча. So emphasized on the last word I guess? I guess it might be what @Alex_ander said just because we have mentioned curses(like spells) before but I’m not sure.

Comment: @MaybelineLee: is there a reason you would not post the original spelling in the post but would in the comments?

Comment: Also, does your friend, by any chance, play the online game Hearthstone?

Comment: @Quassnoi regarding the first question I thought it would make no difference. As for the second, he is a gamer. I saw somewhere that it may be related to starcraft or something.

Comment: As Russian i don't know what is it "пэрча". :))) Mb, - "порча" ? hoodoo, etc

Comment: it can also be a rare or individual slang about a glove -  перчатка, перча (cut version) ... then "расползется" about stitches...

Comment: Context is important.

Answer (score 1):

The word is very similar to intentionally distorted wordform of «теперь»(теперь => теперича => пэрча), which means «now»; so, the phrase may mean “let it spread now”.

But for more accurate intertpretation the context is needed

Answer (score 0):

I guess `пэрча` is distorted `перчатка`.

So "пусть расползётся пэрча" means "Let glove will come apart at the seams"